# Changing x-axis of google chart with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to include line charts on my site, and I am trying to change the x-axis interactively using radio buttons. I am trying to do that from the value of the radio button, but it is considered as a string but not as an object. My experience with JavaScript is minimal, so I appreciate any help.

```
          function drawChart(){
          $.get("sn.csv", function(csvString){
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
          var removeRows = 1;
          while (removeRows--) {
            arrayData.shift();
          }
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
          view.setColumns([0,5]);
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chartContainer"));

          var options = {
              title: "Battery State of Charge (7 days)",
              vAxis: {title: "Charge Level (in Percentage)", minValue:0, maxValue:100},
              legend: 'none'
          };

          var hax = document.getElementsByName('daterange');
          var def = null;
          for (var i=0; i<hax.length;i++){
            hax[i].addEventListener('click', draw1, false);
            if (hax[i].checked){
              def= hax[i];
            }
          }

          if ((def === null) && (hax.length > 0)) {
            def = hax[0];
            def.checked = true;
          }

          draw1({target:def});

          function draw1(sender){
            options.hAxis= null;
            if (sender.target.value !== "{ticks: [{v: 1, f: '00:00'}, {v: 40, f: '04:00'}, {v: 80, f: '08:00'}, {v:120, f: '12:00'}, {v: 160, f: '16:00'}, {v: 180, f: '20:00'}, {v: 200, f: '24:00'}]}") {
              options.hAxis = sender.target.value;
              }
              chart.draw(view, options);
          }

        });
      }
```

```
          <div class="menuSide">    
          <input type="radio" id="d1" name="daterange" value="{ticks:[{v: 1, f: '00:00'}, {v: 40, f: '04:00'}, {v: 80, f: '08:00'}, {v:120, f: '12:00'}, {v: 160, f: '16:00'}, {v: 180, f: '20:00'},
                              {v: 200, f: '24:00'}]}"> <label for="d1">24 hours</label><br> 
          <input type="radio" id="d2" name="daterange" value="{ticks:[{v: 1, f: '00:00'}, {v: 40, f: '08:00'}, {v: 80, f: '16:00'}, {v:120, f: '24:00'}, {v: 160, f: '8:00'}, {v: 180, f: '16:00'},
                              {v: 200, f: '24:00'}]}"> <label for="d2">2 days</label><br> 
          <input type="radio" id="d3" name="daterange" value="{ticks:[{v: 1, f: 'Day 1'}, {v: 40, f: 'Day 2'}, {v: 80, f: 'Day 3'}, {v:120, f: 'Day 4'}, {v: 160, f: 'Day 5'}, {v: 180, f: 'Day 6'},
                              {v: 200, f: 'Day 7'}]}"> <label for="d3">7 days</label><br> 
          </div>
```

The error I get is "Cannot read property 'count' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try parsing the string to an object...

```
options.hAxis = JSON.parse(sender.target.value);
```

**EDIT**

you'll also need to wrap all the object keys and string values in double quotes `"`
you can use single quotes for the value attribute

see following test snippet...

```js
var radio_d1 = document.getElementById('d1');
console.log(JSON.parse(radio_d1.value));
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="d1" name="daterange" value='{"ticks":[{"v": 1, "f": "00:00"}, {"v": 40, "f": "04:00"}, {"v": 80, "f": "08:00"}, {"v":120, "f": "12:00"}, {"v": 160, "f": "16:00"}, {"v": 180, "f": "20:00"},{"v": 200, "f": "24:00"}]}'> <label for="d1">24 hours</label><br>
```

Comment: It works after wrapping the string values in double quotes! Thanks